# Google Search iFrame works in Chrome and firefox but not IE8

Tags: google, javascript, internet-explorer, search, google-chrome

I use Google site search in a IFrame for my sites search engine. When I search for something in Chrome/FireFox "Flight" I get the results page. When I do the same search in IE8 I get 404 error.

Site: www.everydayfiction.com
Search box is on the right hand side in the sidebar.

The strange thing is that in IE8 when I do the search I get the following URL:

```
http://www.everydayfiction.com/search/?cx=007529419963335588653%3Axv8pw52zy20&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&q=Flight
```

But when I do the same search in Chrome/Firefox I get this URL:

```
http://www.everydayfiction.com/search/?cx=007529419963335588653:xv8pw52zy20&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&q=Flight&sa=Search&siteurl=www.everydayfiction.com/search/%3Fcx%3D007529419963335588653%253Axv8pw52zy20%26cof%3DFORID%253A9%26ie%3DUTF-8%26q%3Dfight%26sa%3DSearch
```

***What is going on? 
How do I resolve this?
Suggestion? comments?***

Answer (score 1):

Your search works OK for me in Chrome, Firefox AND IE8 - I get the same results in all browsers - no 404. I get the short URL in the address bar in all browsers, of the form:

```
http://www.everydayfiction.com/search/?  
cx=007529419963335588653%3Axv8pw52zy20&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&q=Flight
```

If I view the frame source in Chrome then I get a long URL *similar* to the long URL you have posted but `rurl=` instead of `siteurl=`

My initial thought was that may be you have third party cookies disabled in IE8 (although TBH I'm not sure why that would produce a 404!?), but I have third party cookies disabled in Chrome and it still works OK.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a mod_rewrite or script-based directive which is forcing the 404 error - the error itself is generated at the webserver level, not by any client-side code (i.e. Google SiteSearch).

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the 404?

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the issue - notably, IE script debugging shows **Access is denied. jquery.js?ver=1.4.2, line 127 character 287** when the main page loads, which I believe may be the reason there are missing GET variables (though the 404 could be related to a variety of other conditions server-side). I'm testing with IE 8.0.6001.18702 when I observe the aforementioned behavior.